# OS X Yosemite - is there a way to name different spaces?

Tags: macos, workspace

I assume the purpose of using multiple spaces (desktops, those that you create when in mission control) is so that you can organize different tasks into different spaces. But is there a way to name different spaces (instead of the default "Desktop 1", "Desktop 2"...), so that I know I have used which desktop for what? For example, "work", "travel planning", etc. I can't seem to find a way for that.

Comment: Set a different background for each desktop

Comment: Just remember the numbers, set up key commands, ctrl/num for each. Takes about a month, after which you'll never forget again.

Comment: I wish Apple would recognize this style of working, but they seem not to like the idea. I've been tempted to try [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com/), which is a paid add-on, but that may [not work in El Capitan](http://blog.binaryage.com/el-capitan-update/).